# Debian installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, grub

I'm new to Linux in general. I tried to install Debian at first; it went ok , the installer told it misses some firmware and I just said ok ok next next and finally I could not install the kernel. After a moment, booted to  Windows, deleted my partition with Linux, downloaded a live+ non-free firmware for gnome.iso, burned it on a USB key with Rufus, and I tried to install it. Used F12, chose "USB", then "install". Now I have an error every time I start with "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported" and a command line starting by grub.

When I follow some tutorial to fix this, the problem is I don't see any partition with Linux when I use the command `lsblk`.

I think my bootloader is messed up, because I can do F12 during start and if I select Windows manage I will start Windows but otherwise it is by default the screen with grub.

I will try to take on another USB key just the non-free firmeware and reinstall Debian the way I did the first time, but this time with a USB key with the firmware ready.

If you have any idea for me, I would like to keep my Windows partition if possible.

Comment: Have you considered using a live image on a USB pendrive?  Then you can try debian without having to dual boot.  See https://www.debian.org/CD/live/

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  In the end it worked i used a live version with non free firmeware and did the calamaris install. To be honest i could, but my teacher at the university told us to install it in dual boot. And i know it will be hard to get used to linux anyway better put the two feet in the plate ( one to be exact as i dual boot) . I don't know if it makes sense to you . Once again thank you

Comment: Here's the standard text about rufus we give on #debian: "rufus is a tool that can be used to make bootable USB devices under Windows. Debian CD/DVD images MUST be written in "DD Mode," otherwise it mangles the installer in cruel and unusual ways, resulting in hard to debug problems."

Answer (score -1):

Hey guys if someone is in the same situation if found how get rid of the GRUB i followed the video on youtube of Murugan S [How to remove GRUB from a dual boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcCouXSpZOY)

I hope it helps someone in the same situation, so now i'm back to windows and i have to install again the Debian hope it will work this time .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).